# css module localIdentName in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, css-modules, css-loader

Is there a default way to set `localIdentName` for css modules without ejecting?

I couldn't find such an option on the official docs so I decided to ask here if someone by any chance knows a way without ejecting and tempering with the `webpack.config.js`.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to eject.

Create-React-App supports css modules right out of the box as of version 2, which is now stable.

Upgrade to v2 (react-scripts@latest) by running yarn upgrade react-scripts@latest.

You just have to create a file with the extension .module.css

For example:

```
.myStyle {
  color: #fff
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from 'mycssmodule.module.css'

export default () => <div className={styles.myStyle}>We are styled!</div>
```

To read more - https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet

Comment: I read your question. localIdentName is set to use css-modules, but in create-react-app you cannot set that without ejecting. Hence, I have written the way you can use css-modules in create-react-app.

Comment: That is what my understanding was after reading your question. If that is not the case, please explain a bit more what are looking for. :-)

Comment: I was missing the part where I cannot set `localIdentName` without ejecting that was my question, not about how to set css modules without ejecting, but your comments clarify this, thanks.